# Чем объясняется такой механизм перезаписи полей объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упускаю, стремясь понять следующее поведение перезаписи полей объекта в javascript в таком вот коде?

```
const nodeList = {
    head: null,
    tail: null,
    append: function(value)  {
        const node = {value, next: null};
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }  else {
            this.tail.next = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }
    }
}

nodeList.append('a')
nodeList.append('b')
```

Конкретно непонятно, как после строк

```
this.tail.next = node;
this.tail = node;
```

новый объект *node* попадает в *head*, ведь мы не обращаемся к нему. То есть в результате мы получаем вот такой объект:

```
{
  head: {value: 'a', next: {value: 'b', next: null}},
  tail: {value: 'b', next: null}
}
```

Если же сымитировать это поведение так

```
const nodeList = {
  head: null,
  tail: null
}

nodeList.head = {value: 'a', next: null}
nodeList.tail = {value: 'a', next: null}

nodeList.tail.next = {value: 'b', next: null}
nodeList.tail = {value: 'b', next: null}
```

То мы получаем такой объект, что в принципе, ожидаемо

```
{
  head: {value: 'a', next: null}
  tail: {value: 'b', next: null}
}
```

Почему такая разница, механизм же вроде бы одинаковый. Что я не понимаю?

Comment: что-то с имитацией у вас не то. заполняете tail.next а потом tail перезаписываете целиком. В исходном то примере у вас промежуточный node есть.

Comment: Именно это я и не понимаю. В коде объекта с методом append тоже сначала записывается this.tail.next, а затем this.tail перезаписывается целиком. И в результате - объект и в this.head в соответствующей вложенности, и в this.tail. Непонятно именно это.

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите вот на эту строку `this.tail.next = node;` и скажите себе, что тут происходит?

Comment: Подумали? А теперь делается вот это `this.tail = node;`, и tail становится node. Так что все верно

Comment: Alexander Chernin, в этой строке полю next объекта, который в поле tail объекта nodeList, присваиваем ссылку на новый объект node. Чувствую, что где-то здесь я недопонимаю) Но что именно, не допру никак))

Comment: возьмите бумажку и карандаш и нарисуйте все манипуляции с этим односвязным списком от руки. и учитите, что в отличие от вашей имитации, где вы везде создаете новые копии, тут у вас будут ссылки (стрелки) на одни и те же объекты.

Comment: Так, значит ссылки... Благодарю.

Comment: Alexander Chernin, teran, огромное спасибо! Разобрался.